# Set aliases in PowerShell using doskey macros

Tags: powershell, alias, doskey

Is this possible? I have tried [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2007/07/09/getting-doskey-macros-to-work-in-powershell/), but it doesn't work.
I have a macrofile with about 50 or so `doskey` macros, which is used in `cmd.exe`.

I run something like:

```
doskey /exename=powershell.exe /macrofile=C:\macrofile.txt
```

or

```
doskey /exename=powershell.exe blah=echo blah
```

But trying the command `blah` gives an error:

> blah : The term 'blah' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

If I list them with `doskey /macros:powershell.exe` however, they're all there.

Is there a way I can create 50 aliases in PowerShell to map to these macros? The `Set-Alias` cmdlet doesn't help much since the commands are more complex than calling a simple PowerShell cmdlet. There are posts that suggest creating functions in a .ps1 script, however, this would work only if I manually write 50 different functions for each of the 50 macros in the file. Also, this would involve maintaining two files - the macrofile for cmd and a PowerShell script which translates these into functions.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks, edited question to include details.

Comment: I believe this works if you don't use `PSReadLine` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PSReadLine` module (ships with PowerShell 5.0 or later) is not compatible with `doskey`, which relies on the native console input functions. I tested on Windows 10/PowerShell 5:

```
PS C:\> Remove-Module PSReadLine
PS C:\> doskey /exename=powershell.exe g=Get-Location
PS C:\> g

Path
----
C:\
```

Comment: Verified! Works, thanks! It seems that Powershell 3.0 might also have the 'PsReadLine' module. I tried (on Win10): 'powershell -version 2.0' and 'powershell -version 3.0' without removing this module and the doskey macro worked on 2.0 but not 3.0.

Comment: FWIW, it's worth considering ditching `doskey` and the native console input features for the  `PSReadline` module. I think the extra gained functionality is worth the switch.